# Scrapy crawl all sitemap links

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, sitemap

I want to crawl all he links present in the sitemap.xml of a fixed site. I've came across Scrapy's **SitemapSpider**. So far i've extracted all the urls in the sitemap. Now i want to crawl through each link of the sitemap. Any help would be highly useful. The code so far is:

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "xyz"
    allowed_domains = ["xyz.nl"]
    sitemap_urls = ["http://www.xyz.nl/sitemap.xml"] 

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.url
```

Comment: If you can post a valid url for the domain, then it will be easier to check the code

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you could create new request objects to crawl the urls created by the SitemapSpider and parse the responses with a new callback:

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "xyz"
    allowed_domains = ["xyz.nl"]
    sitemap_urls = ["http://www.xyz.nl/sitemap.xml"] 

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.url
        return Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_sitemap_url)

    def parse_sitemap_url(self, response):
        # do stuff with your sitemap links
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add sitemap_rules to process the data in the crawled urls, and you can create as many as you want.
For instance say you have a page named http://www.xyz.nl//x/ you want to create a rule:

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'xyz'
    sitemap_urls = 'http://www.xyz.nl/sitemap.xml'
    # list with tuples - this example contains one page 
    sitemap_rules = [('/x/', parse_x)]

    def parse_x(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        paragraph = sel.xpath('//p').extract()

        return paragraph
```

Comment: The `parse` method is called by default if no rules are specified; I believe the original post was correct in that regard